# Swapping columns in two-dimensional arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, swap

I would like to swap the first and second columns in my two-dimensional array. How should I use the `swap()` function there?

```
void swapp(int tab[5][6], int n = 5, int m = 6) {
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      tab[n][m] = j + i;
      swap(tab[n][1], tab[n][0]);
      cout << "{" << tab[n][m] << "}" << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your mistake was that you thought two loops were necessary for what is a one dimensional operation. If you look at the code you can see that `j` isn't being used at all, which is a clue that it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `n` and `m` means the size of matrix:

```
void swapp(int tab[5][6],int n=5,int m=6)
{
    if(m >= 2){ // check if we have at least 2 columns (to swap)
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ // use swap for each rows
            swap(tab[i][1],tab[i][0]); // swap data in this row
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These statements

```
  tab[n][m]=j+i;
  swap(tab[n][1],tab[n][0]);
  cout<<"{"<<tab[n][m]<<"}"<<" ";
```

invoke undefined behavior because there are accesses memory beyond the array because for example if an array has `n` rows or columns then the valid range of indices for rows or columns is `[0, n)`.

To swap two columns of a two-dimensional array it is enough to write only one loop.

You could write a general function that swaps any two specified columns in an integer array.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>

template <size_t M, size_t N>
void swapp( int ( &a )[M][N], size_t col1, size_t col2 )
{
    if ( col1 < N && col2 < N && col1 != col2 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
        {
            std::swap( a[i][col1], a[i][col2] );
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 3, N = 4;
    int a[M][N] = 
    {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4 },
        { 5,  6,  7,  8 },
        { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
    };
    
    
    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    swapp( a, 0, 1 );
    
    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 

 2  1  3  4 
 6  5  7  8 
10  9 11 12
```